# How can I install viber and whatsapp on my Gsm tablet with ics 4.0.1

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, viber-messenger

I have tried many times to download viber or whatsapp from play store but it shows that its not compatible with my device... can anyone help??

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0by-96VOXJk

Comment: Step by step instruction is mentioned on how to install whatsApp on WiFi tab.